# Use of is Keyword in C# to declare variable inline

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I am currently working on a C# project using v4.6.2 and Visual Studio just suggested a code change to the code below.

My question is, I have never seen the `is` keyword used to create a new variable instance in this manner.

The original code was:

```
var authInfo = inputs.FirstOrDefault(i =>
    typeof(SoapAuthenticationBase).IsAssignableFrom(i.GetType()));

if (authInfo is SoapAuthenticationBase)
```

Visual Studio 2017 suggested this:

```
if (inputs.FirstOrDefault(i =>
        typeof(SoapAuthBase).IsAssignableFrom(i.GetType())) 
        is SoapAuthBase authenticationContract)
```

I checked Microsoft's documentation on the ['is' keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) and found nothing that explained this syntax.

What version of C# was 'is' added in this way?

Comment: The original code also declares a variable using the `is` keyword, is that a typo? Nevermind, already edited.

Comment: It's [Pattern matching with `is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) which is C#7

Comment: see here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/

Comment: @TimSchmelter: "I don't understand the use case of it" - it saves a line under the assumption that you actually want to do something with the variable cast to the type it was checked for.

Comment: [C# 7.0](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/152/c-sharp-7-is-operator-patterns-you-wont-need-as-as-often)

Comment: Your question is tagged C# 4.0, the Visual Studio 2017 suggestion is a C# 7.0 feature. If you cannot use C# 7.0 then ignore the suggestion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes except we are using C# 4.6.2, so why would Visual Studio let a C# 7 syntax work in C# 6?

Comment: `.NET 4.6.2 != C# 4.6.2`. .NET 4.6.2 is the Framework version, i.e. what is available in the Framework like `System.IO`. C# 7.0 is the language version and you need the right compiler. .NET versions and C# versions do not have to match. For example, in one project I have .NET 4.5.1 but compile with C# 7.2

Comment: @BenHoffman if you use VS 2017 for new projects the default language version is "latest major version" which is C# 7, not C# 6

Comment: My question is why would Visual Studio suggest checking against a different type (`SoapAuthenticationBase` becomes `SoapAuthBase`) and also why it would refactor the variable to a different name (`authInfo` becomes `authenticationContract`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature is called *pattern matching* and it was introduced in the c# language in version 7. In your example its not very clear, but consider the following canonical example of `Equals` overriding:

```
public override bool Equals(obj other)
{
    if (obj is Foo)
    {
        return Equals((Foo)obj);
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is essentially wasteful because you are checking the type twice: once to see if its in fact a `Foo`, and then again when performing the cast. It seems unnecessarily verbose.

Pattern matching allows a much more concise syntax:

```
public override bool Equals(obj other)
{
    if (obj is Foo foo)
    {
        return Equals(foo);
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can read more on this feature [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/).

Comment: The first case is slightly contrived, in practice you would use `as` and check for null instead, but the pattern matching is an improvement either way.

Comment: @richzilla and what if `Foo` is a value type?

Answer (score 2):

In your first snipper, the `is` keyword checks whether the thing on the left is an instance of the type on the right. `is` returns a boolean, the `FirstOrDefault` call is returning either null or an instance of `SoapAuthenticationBase` which is being assigned to your variable.

As @Ashley Medway pointed out, the second code snippet is actually an example of C# pattern matching. `authenticationContract` is an instance of `SoapAuthBase` that will only have a value if the thing on the left is an instance of it. If not, the entire statement will return false.

That said, personally i find your original code more readable. I would be inclined to ignore VS, and let the compiler sort it all out later.

Comment: This isn't strictly correct. You are describing how an an older `is` check works like `if(variable is type)` but the way its being used in the questions is [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression)

Comment: *"The second code snippet is cutting out the intermediate variable assignment"* Then what is `authenticationContract` in the second code snippet if not a new variable?

Comment: It isn't so much that it isn't a new variable so much as how it is _scoped_. When pattern matching like this, `authenticationContract` is scoped to the `if()`. Also, in cases where it is `false`, it won't create the variable whereas the prior code will create a `null` instance of `authInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

While the suggestion is creating a new variable, it is scoped to the `if` (i.e. much narrower).

```
var authInfo = inputs.FirstOrDefault(i =>
    typeof(SoapAuthenticationBase).IsAssignableFrom(i.GetType()));
if (authInfo is SoapAuthenticationBase){
   // authInfo exists
}
// authInfo exists
```

It's basically suggesting you drop the existing `authInfo` instance you're declaring.

```
if (inputs.FirstOrDefault(i =>
        typeof(SoapAuthBase).IsAssignableFrom(i.GetType())) 
        is SoapAuthBase authenticationContract){
  // authenticationContract exists
}
// authenticationContract does not exist
```

Comment: "It isn't creating a new variable" Yes, it *is* creating a new variable.  It allows you to drop another variable, so the number of variables before and after the change is the same, because you're *moving* the variable declaration to a different line, but it's still there.

Comment: Okay, I should be clearer. It technically is creating the variable `authenticationContract`, but this var is scoped to the `if` whereas the prior `authInfo` variable is scoped to the method (guessing on this one since it's a small snippet).